# Set popover height

Tags: safari-extension

I would like to be able to dynamically change the height of my popover window when I click on the toolbar item. The toolbar item and popover already work fine. The code is executed in the popovers javascript.

This page suggests that it can be done but they don't provide any examples:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingPopovers/AddingPopovers.html

```
You can change the height and width properties of your popover at runtime.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E.g., from a script running in the popover:

```
safari.self.height = 400;
```

If you want to set the height from the global page:

```
safari.extension.popovers[0].width = 600;
```

Comment: Once you set the popover for ex. 600, if you want to go back to 400 I found out that doesn't work. Does anybody found a way?